# Make Cookie expire according to URL-variable with PHP

Tags: php, cookies, time, setcookie

I'm working on a new product/website, where the homepage (not the subpages) should be closed for visitors until the website launches. The launch-date should be read out of the URL like this:

```
website.com/some-subpage?launch=0421
```

In this example the homepage should be accessible to the visitor from the 21th (21) of April (04).

For this I want to do that if somebody visits "some-subpage" (or any other subpage, doesnt matter), a cookie should be set like this:

- Cookie-Name: Launch
- Cookie-Value: 0421
- Cookie expiration: At the launch, so in this case the 21th of April

Here is what I have so far:

```
<?php
if ($_GET['launch'] != "null") {
date_default_timezone_set('Europe/Berlin');
$launchdate = $_GET['launch'];

$launchdatenew->format('*********'); // Here I probably need to convert the "0421" to a readable time, but I dont know how
// or probably using this version?
$launchdatenew = date_format(date_create_from_format('m d', $launchdate), '*********'); // Here I probably need to convert the "0421" to a readable time, but I dont know how

setcookie("Launch", $launchdate, $launchdatenew, "/"); // The Cookie-Name should be "Launch", the value "0421", and it should expire when the launch starts

} ?>
```

Could you please help me finishing this? I don't know how to convert the "0421" into a new format that could be set as the expiration-date for the cookie. My PHP-skills are almost zero unfortunately.

Thank you very much!
Bye,
Imre

Comment: Are you getting errors?  What does not work?  Obvious thing that jumps out here is your trusting user land data `$_GET['launch'];` and then storing that in user land too.

Comment: No, I did not test it yet, as I'm sure it wont work (I dont know how to convert the "0421" into a new format that could be set as the expiration-date for the cookie.
Its not a problem, that users could manipulate it - they wont.

Comment: They will. Never trust them.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'll show you then how to set the `expire` on that cookie based off the date in `$launch`.

Assuming that will always be in format 'mmdd' then with some simple string manipulation...

```
$launchDateStr = '0421';

$launchTime = mktime(0, 0, 0, substr($launchDateStr, 0, 2), substr($launchDateStr, 2));

$ttl = $launchTime - time(); //just an example... find seconds between now and launch

setcookie("launch", $launchDateStr, $launchTime, "/");
```

caveats... this ignores year.  You should not trust user data.  All this can be spoofed.

Comment: Thank you ficuscr, this helps me further! How do I calculate seconds between now and $launchTime? The fact that this ignores year is not a problem. Thanks for the hint not trusting user data - but as soon as they click a link with a "launch"-variable, the cookie will be set - and existing cookies wont be overwritten (I will do this with an IF), so changing the launch-variable and visiting this new link wont do anything. BTW, shouldn't the "$ttl" be the expiration date?

Comment: *"How do I calculate seconds between now and $launchTime?"*  See TTL example.  *"Shouldn't the "$ttl" be the expiration date?"*  No.  It wants the unix timestamp for that datetime, not the seconds remaining.

Comment: And why do we need the "$ttl" part? After calculating it, its never used, is it?

Comment: No, I mistakenly also started out thinking I'd need it for cookie.  Then figured it might be a useful thing to leave as it might well be your next question so I just left that line to show how you would get it if needed.

Comment: Thank you very-very much for your help, ficuscr! I tested it now and it works perfectly! (btw, at setcookie you misspelled "launchDateStr" which took me a few minutes to find out that there is missing a "n" :) ).